# datetime display and timezone converting in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, date, datetime

in settings.py file:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' 
USE_TZ = True
```

in models.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone

date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now())
```

before pip install pytz，date field in mysql db stored as UTC time, and date in front end webpage display as localtime. but after pip install pytz,date field in mysql db stored as UTC time, at the same time date in front end webpage display as UTC time too.

What is the reason for this? 
How to do make sure that after pip install pytz，date field in mysql db stored as UTC time, and date in front end webpage display as localtime?
BTW, which library is more easily done than pytz?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `TIME_ZONE` setting to your local time's `pytz`.

e.g.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dubai'
```

Comment: I treat this website as global website, so TIME_ZONE not set as a appointed timezone. is not it?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates

Comment: thanks a lot, this problem is resolved according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/.